# Find URL structure in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I would like to recreate old pages that were online 2 years ago. Unfortunately, all I have is the old htaccess file. Is there a way to find all used URLs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not if it was a lot of non-dynamic pages that the .htaccess wouldn't know about.  Did you check the [wayback machine](http://archive.org/web/web.php) to explore the old site?

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` does not store any information about pages or their urls. The only possible information to get is a redirection mechanism and/or some information regarding folders structure, if such was used. If you paste the source of your file here, one could help you with this. In general - in the most optimistic scenario you will just get a set of rules in the form of

```
regular Expression --> server query
```

(unless author did enumerate all the urls instead of using regular expressions)

Check the http://archive.org/web/web.php for some cached versions of your website.